# How to solve $\sin x\cos x-x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I solve the equation:

$$\sin x\cos x-x=0\text{ ?}$$

They are not the same kind

(trig and polynomial).

Thanks.

Comment: There are rarely closed form solutions in this sort of situation. But here we have $\sin 2x=2x$, with obvious solution $x=0$, and no other solution since the absolute value of $sin t$ is less than the absolute value of $t$ except at $t=0$.

Comment: May be, this could be of interest to you (I hope and wish) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation

Comment: For such questions, draw the graph of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\sin x\cos x = x
$$
$$
2\sin x \cos x = 2x
$$
$$
\sin(2x) = 2x
$$
$$
\sin u = u
$$

Draw the graphs of $y=\sin u$ and $y=u$ superimposed on each other.  You see that $y=0$ when $u=0$ in *both* graphs.  That says $u=0$ is one solution.  The question is whether there are others.

Notice that the slope of $\sin u$ with respect to $u$ is $1$ when $u=0$, since $\sin'=\cos$.  Then notice that the slope of the sine function is smaller at all other points than it is at points where its slope is $1$.  That tells you the graph of the sine function must be *below* the graph of $y=u$ when $u>0$ and *above* the graph of $y=u$ when $u<0$.  That tells you whether there are any other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is the only solution.

If $x \neq 0$ we know that $| \sin(x) | < |x|$ and $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$. This implies that
$$
|\sin(x)\cos(x)| < |x|$$

and hence 
$$|x-\sin(x) \cos(x)| \geq |x|-|\sin(x) \cos(x)| >0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the property

$2\sin x\cos x=\sin (2x)$

Let $f(x)=sin2x - 2x$

$f'(x)=2\cos (2x)-2$ which is zero at $0,2\pi,...$

Also, $-1-2x\le f(x)\le 1-2x$ which means the function is contained between two lines.

Finally, $f'(x)\le 0$ which means the function is decreasing.
Also, $f(-\frac{\pi}{4})>0$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{4})<0$.This means, there has to be at least one point where it crosses the x-axis.
Since the curve decreases continuously, it intersects x-axis only once.

For solving such questions, try drawing the graph to find roots.

Comment: But still I'll have difficulty because it's not the same type.

Comment: it is the same type, he used the additional formuals

Comment: How it's the same? One is trig $sin2x$ and the other is polynomial $2x$

Comment: yes it is and your original equation is this also

Comment: So the answer didn't help me, because it's still the same kind.

Comment: what kind do you exspect? we can't solve this equation  explicit for $x$

Comment: Why not? For example $x=0$ is a solution

Comment: yes the is the only solution it comes from intuition but not from solving the equation by isolating $x$

Comment: So, we can't prove that it's the only solution?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: @Dave : It's not hard to prove it's the only solution. See my answer below.  I suspect that what Dr. Sonnhard Graubner means is that one can't solve it simply by using algebra. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\sin u=u$ has only one solution: $u=0$. To see this, you may suppose $u>0$ because if $u<0$ is a solution, $-u$ is also a solution. You also may suppose 01$ and $\sin u\le 1.

Now, on the interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$, the sine function is strictly concave, hence its curve is under its tangent at any point in the interval, in particuler under its tangent at origin, which has equation $y=x$.