# solve for $x$: $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{5}{6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to solve for x the following equation without root finding:

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: Wolfram alpha just does it numerically...getting $x\sim \pm 1.02674$.  I expect there's no simpler form.

Comment: I'm surprised how challenging such simple equations!

Comment: Exactly? Don't think so. But there are plenty of nice numerical methods, Taylor series approximations and so on. But you're aware of that already.

Comment: It's not as surprising as you might think. There's a lot of numbers out there. Not all of them are as simple as, let's say, solutions to polynomials with integer coefficients.

Comment: If you assume small angles then you can obtain $x=\pm 1$ fairly fast else it's a bit grim as stated. You can't avoid finding roots though because even to lowest order the LHS expansion is $1 - x^2/3! + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$

Comment: Does anyone know how to show that this equation doesn't have a closed form solution using standard functions, or some such similar result? (The answers so far seem to do exactly what the OP asks them not to do: use some form of root finding.)

Comment: @SimonS: that depends on the meaning of closed form. By Lagrange's inversion formula, we may solve $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{5}{6}$ in terms of a pretty complicated series. Is that a closed form?

Comment: By closed form I mean it is possible to write an expression for $x$ that requires a finite number of calculations using combinations of standard functions; for instance, the expression for $x_0$ in your answer below. However, the OP may have a different definition.

Answer (score 4):

There is no closed form solution, but since $\sin(x)$ is a concave function on $(0,\pi)$ and $\sin'(0)=1$, there is a unique real and positive solution to $\sin(x)=\frac{5}{6}x$. We may use a step of Newton's method with starting point $x_0=1$ get a tight approximation of such solution:
$$ x_1\approx 1-\frac{\sin 1-5/6}{\cos 1-5/6}\approx 1.02777. $$
An even better starting point is given by the solution of
$$ \exp\left(\frac{5x^2}{x^2-30}\right)=\frac{5}{6} $$
i.e. by
$$ x_0 = \sqrt{\frac{30 \log\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}{5+\log\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)}}\approx 1.0273477$$
or by the solution of 
$$ \frac{60-7x^2}{60+3x^2}=\frac{5}{6}, $$
i.e. by
$$ x_0 = 2\sqrt{\frac{5}{19}} \approx 1.026. $$
By using the Padé approximant in the origin $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with $\partial p=\partial q=4$, we get the almost exact solution
$$ x\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{977} \left(13405-\sqrt{166152805}\right)}.$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Hi Jack ! How did you arrive to the *better starting point* ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: the first approximation was $\frac{\sin x}{x}\approx e^{-x^2/6}$, then I took an approximant for $\log\frac{\sin x}{x}$ capable to grasp the $x^4$ term, too.

Comment: Nice way, for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$x=6/5\cdot\sin(6/5\cdot\sin(6/5\cdot \sin(6/5\cdot\sin(\cdots))))$$

But from convergence point of view Newton is faster

Answer (score 1):

Equations which mix polynomial and trigonometric terms do not show analytical solutions (this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$) and numerical methods should be used.

However, some rather good approximations can be made and, for your curiosity, I give you the links to two questions of mine ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska)).

Using the beautiful $$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$  proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician, your equation becomes $$\frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}=\frac 56 x$$ which reduces to a simple quadratic $$-\frac{10 x^2}{3}+\left(\frac{10 \pi }{3}-16\right) x-\frac{25 \pi ^2}{6}+16 \pi=0$$ for which the solution to keep is  $$x=\frac{1}{40} \left(-96+20 \pi +\sqrt{9216+3840 \pi -1600 \pi ^2}\right)\approx 1.02288 $$ while the exact solution, obtained using Newton method, would be $\approx 1.02674$.

Now, knowing that the solution is close to $1$, we could approximate $\sin(x)$ using its simplest Padé approximant built at $x=1$; this should give $$\sin(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2} (x-1) (2 \cos (1)+\sin (1) \tan (1))+\sin (1)}{1+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)
   \tan (1)}$$ which, again, reduces to a quadratic the solution of which being $\approx 1.02676$.

Another way could be to use the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ around $x=\frac \pi 3$ which is $$\sin(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3}
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2-\frac{1}{12} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)^3+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^4\right)$$ Limiting to  first order, the solution would then be $$x_{(1)}=\frac{1}{2} \left(3 \sqrt{3}-\pi \right)\approx 1.02728$$  Limiting to  second order, the solution would then be $$x_{(2)}=\frac{1}{3} \left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+\pi +\sqrt{\frac{2}{3} \left(29-5 \sqrt{3}
   \pi \right)}\right)\approx 1.02674$$