# Find the radius of a circle given only the length of a chord and its segment.

Tags: geometry, circles

Suppose that in the following diagram, I am only given c and s, the lengths of a chord and its segment.

Is it possible to find the exact value of the radius using c and s?

Every formula I found involves using h (distance from centre of chord to centre of the arc) or theta but I am only given c and s. Is there a simple way to find h or theta then use it to find R?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2284522/265466.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=R\theta$$

$$c=2R\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

Dividing we get,

$$\frac{c}{s} = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$

where $t=\theta/2$ and so $0< t < \pi/2$. Since $\sin(x)/x$ is 1-1 on $(0,\pi/2)$, a unique solution $t$ exists (assuming $2s/\pi < c < s$) and $R = \frac{s}{2t}$

Comment: What if theta is unknown? I only know c and s. Can I find theta using c and s?

Comment: @user6005857. Then, you need to solve the equation. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation

Comment: This also could be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284522/how-to-find-the-maximum-height-perpendicular-to-arc-without-knowing-radius-of-th/2286314#2286314