# Exact Answer: Cut a circular pizza into 16 Pieces, 12 of them with equal area. Find where the cuts should be made to satisfy these conditions.

Tags: circles, approximation, area, rotations

**EDIT:**

It's almost been a year since I attempted this problem, so I decided to come back to it.

One thing I was trying to do before was find a "closed form" of this problem, but really I wanted a way to infinitely approximate $w$ while isolating $w$ to one side of the equation.

Going back to a previously found equation:

> $4w^2 = arcsin(w) + w\sqrt{1 - w^2}$

---

**TAYLOR EXPANSIONS** 
I kept the Taylor expansion of $arcsin(x)$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the back of my mind decided to finally use them. (Note, I will also prove the following using integration later.)

Where $arcsin(w) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(2n+1)}$ 
And $w\sqrt{1 - w^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)}$ 
 
$\implies 4w^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(2n+1)} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)}$ 
$\implies 4w^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(2n+1)} + \frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)}$
$\implies 4w^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} (\frac{1}{(2n+1)} + \frac{1}{(-2n+1)}) $
$\implies 4w^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} (\frac{2}{(2n+1)(-2n+1)}) $
$\implies 4w^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n-1} (n!)^2(2n+1)(-2n+1)} $
$\implies w^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2(2n+1)(-2n+1)} $
$\implies w =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n}}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2(2n+1)(-2n+1)} $
let $a_{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2(2n+1)(-2n+1)}$ 
$\implies w =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}w^{2n} $

**INTEGRAL PROOF** 
 
$2w^2 = \int_{0}^{w}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}dx$ 
$\implies \int_{0}^{w}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!x^{2n}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)}}dx$ 
$\implies [\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!x^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)(2n+1)}]_{0}^{w}$ 
 
$\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)(2n+1)}$ 
 
$2w^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2(-2n+1)(2n+1)}$ 
 
$w^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2(-2n+1)(2n+1)}$ 
 
$w = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!w^{2n}}{2^{2n+1} (n!)^2(-2n+1)(2n+1)}$ 
 
$\implies w =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}w^{2n} $

---

**RECURSIVE APPROXIMATION**
let $g_{k}$ be a recursive function for insertion purposes. 
Where $g_0 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}}$ 
 
Similarly $g_k = \sum_{n_k=0}^{\infty}{a_{n_k}*(g_{k-1})^{2*n_k}}$ 
 
This substitution method is by reinserting $w$ into the right side an infinite amount of times recursively until it disappears from the right side entirely (as it will never reach the base case).

> Therefore, $w=\lim{_{k\rightarrow\infty}}{g_k}$

This is also proven to work computationally in both python and Mathematica.

---

**WORK PREVIOUS**
I've recently been stumped on a *simple* pizza cutting problem that was brought to me by one of my friends at work.

> Cut a pizza into 16 pieces where 12 of the pieces have equal
>   area. More specifically A=B=C=D=E=F=G=H=I=J=K=L in [image]
>   Find where the pizza should be cut to satisfy this problem.

My first step was to make a visualization of the pizza [in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ppclpliyax).
From this visualization (and later in algebra) you can see that the size of the pizza doesn't matter, and the length of the inner square $w$ remains constant in relation to r.

My next step was to isolate a symmetric quarter of the pizza  [image] and find a relation between the known formulas. The area shaded in blue at the bottom was the key to me finding the formula that I need to be solved.

> From this quarter, we know that: 
> $3(wr)^2 + s = \frac14 \pi r^2 $

---

From the triangle, we know: 

 To $\theta,$ 
 $wr$ is opposite
 $\sqrt {r^2 - (wr)^2}$ is adjacent and 
$r $ is the hypotenuse.

 $sin(\theta) = \frac{wr}{r} = w $ 
 $\implies \theta = \arcsin(w) $

(Triangle Area):
 $\frac12b* h$
 $b=w*r$
 $h=\sqrt{r^2 - (wr)^2}$

 $\implies \frac{1}{2}*w\sqrt{1 - w^2}*r^2$

(Arced Area):
$\frac{\theta}{2\pi} * \pi r^2 = \frac{\theta}{2} * r^2 = \frac{\arcsin(w)}{2}*r^2$

The combined area must equal $2(wr)^2$ *because A=B=C=D=E=F=G=H=I=J=K=L ...*

$[\frac{1}{2}*w\sqrt{1 - w^2}*r^2]$ + [$\frac{\arcsin(w)}{2}*r^2] = 2(wr)^2$

 ... 
 Multiply both sides by $\frac{2}{r^2}$ 
 ...

> The equation in question: 
>  $w\sqrt{1 - w^2} + arcsin(w) = 4w^2$

---

Eureka!
So plug and chug into Wolfram Alpha [right](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=w*sqrt(1%20-%20w%5E2)%20%2B%20arcsin(w)%20%3D%204w%5E2)? 
Sadly that only works for *approximations* of the answer. $(w ≈ 0.480068840868035244581566735...)$
I was wondering if it's even possible to have an *exact* answer for this problem, or if it's impossible due to the approximate nature of $\arcsin(x)$'s Taylor expansion.

---

*Note: Approaching this problem by using the accumulation function of a circle up to **wr** will yield the same result. 
Because $\int\sqrt{r^2 - x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2} * x\sqrt{r^2 - x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\arcsin(\frac{x}{r})*r^2 + C$*

---

Alternate Forms of the equation: 
**Trig Approach:** 
$sin(\theta)*cos(\theta) + \theta = 4sin^2(\theta)$ 
**Hyperbolic Trig Approach:** 
$(4+i)e^{-2i\theta} + (4-i)e^{2i\theta} = 8 - 4\theta$ 
$(θ≈0.5007331859243733442276693702257483572649...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the problem boils down to finding the $z\in(0,1)$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{z}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = 2z^2, $$
i.e. to solving
$$ z\sqrt{1-z^2}+\arcsin(z)=4z^2 \tag{A}$$
or, by setting $z=\sin\theta$ and $\varphi=2\theta$,
$$ 4\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi=4-\varphi. $$
Solving $(A)$ is essentially equivalent to solving [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) (see also [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2578840/44121)).
An approximate solution can be derived from the [Shafer-Fink](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) approximation 
$$\arcsin(x)\approx\frac{3x}{2+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{B} $$
leading to $z\approx 0.48$. Such initial approximation can be refined through Newton's method, till reaching $z\approx 0.480068840868$, but there is no hope of getting a nice closed form for the solution of the trascendental equation appearing in (A).

Comment: Aha! Thanks for answering this! I do believe you're right. After looking at your links, this equation is a Transcendental Equation which may or may not have a closed form answer. (To those that don't know, things like $e^x = x$ or $sin(\theta) = \theta$). And though a closed form may exist for this problem, it's not possible (at least that we know of) to solve for it.

Comment: Hi Jack! Thanks for originally guiding me to a solution. Since you've answered I've been reading a lot about approximations, Taylor series and transcendental equations. I've edited my answer to reflect the ugly closed form of w I found through infinite recursion.