# How to find the central angle given a line and circle segment?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: img]

I know the length of the line segment $AB$ and the length od the circle arc $AB$. How can I express the angle $\alpha$ in terms of those two?

I tried many things but I always get some trig function of alpha in terms of itself. I'm not sure if there exist some simple formula, but eiter way any input is appreciated.

Comment: No way nice and explicit.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $\overset{\frown}{AB}=r\alpha$ where $r$ denotes the radius of the circle. Secondly $$\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{AB}{2r}=\frac{\alpha AB}{2\overset{\frown}{AB}}$$ therefore $\alpha$ is the solution of: $$\frac{1}{x}\sin{\frac{x}{2}}=\lambda$$ from here we need numerical method to approach $\alpha$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you clarify what do you mean by  λ?

Comment: $\lambda:=\frac{AB}{2\overset{\frown}{AB}}$

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how to write the symbol for the arc, I'll use the notation  $\widehat{BA}$ for the arc.

Let $\frac{\alpha}{2}=k$. As you might know 
$$\begin{cases} \widehat{BA}=2\pi r·\big(\frac{\alpha}{360°}\big)=2\pi r·\big(\frac{k}{180°}\big) \\ [AB]=\sin\big( \frac{\alpha}{2}\big)·r=\sin(k)·r \end{cases}$$

Dividing $$\frac{\widehat{BA}}{[AB]}=\frac{2\pi k}{180°·\sin(k)}$$ and if you're working with radians $$\frac{\widehat{BA}}{[AB]}=\frac{2k}{\sin(k)}=\frac{\alpha}{\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})}$$

For which I don't think you'll find further simplifications...

Comment: Which means that $k$ is the solution to $\sin(k)/k = {\rm si}(k) = \frac{2[AB]}{\widehat{BA}}$, i.e., one would need an inverse to the sinc function. However, it is known that the sinc function has no simple inverse.

Comment: Exactly Florian

Answer (score 1):

Starting from HAMIDINE SOUMARE's answer, you need to solve for $x$
$$\frac{1}{x}\sin{\frac{x}{2}}=\lambda$$ for which, as said, you need some numerical method.

For simplicity, let $x=2y$ and $\mu=2\lambda$ which makes the equation to be
$$\sin(y)=\mu\, y$$ which is basically the question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation).

To make it short, for $0 \leq y \leq \pi$, you could get quite good *estimates* using different kind of approximations such as
$$\sin(y) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -y) y}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -y) y}\tag 1$$ or, simpler but less accurate
$$\sin(y) \simeq \frac{120}{\pi ^5}(\pi -y) y\tag 2$$ Another one, which is quite good but does not respect the values at the end point
$$\sin(y) \simeq \frac{12 \left(\pi ^2-10\right)}{\pi ^3}-\frac{60 \left(\pi ^2-12\right) }{\pi
   ^4}y+\frac{60 \left(\pi ^2-12\right)}{\pi ^5}y^2\tag 3$$

Approximations $(1)$ and $(3)$ reduce the problem to a quadratic equation in $y$ while Approximations $(2)$ makes the problem to be a linear equation.

Now, if you want to polish the root, using one of these estimates for $y_0$, apply Newton method to iterate according to
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{\sin (y_n)-y_n \cos (y_n)}{\mu -\cos (y_n)}$$

**Edit**

As Yves Daoust answered, for small values of $y$, you could use Taylor series
$$\frac{\sin (y)}{y}=1-\frac{y^2}{6}+\frac{y^4}{120}-\frac{y^6}{5040}+\frac{y^8}{362880}+O\left(y^{10}\right)$$ and use series reversion to get
$$y=t+\frac{t^3}{40}+\frac{107 t^5}{67200}+\frac{3197 t^7}{24192000}+O\left(t^9\right)\qquad \text{where}\qquad t=\sqrt{6(1-\mu)}\tag 4$$

For example, using $\mu=\frac 12$, the different equations would respectively lead to $y_{(1)}=1.89477$, $y_{(2)}=1.86651 $, $y_{(3)}=1.88030 $, $y_{(4)}=1.89296 $ while the "exact" solution would be $1.89549$.

$y_{(2)}=\pi -\frac{\pi ^5 \mu }{120}$ being the simplest to obtain, let us use it as $y_0$ in Newton method; the following iterates would be produced
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
 0 & 1.866510634 \\
 1 & 1.896000423 \\
 2 & 1.895494415 \\
 3 & 1.895494267
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It is very informativne, especally your question about sin(x) = ax. Can x be expressed as an infinite sum or product? I am looking for that, but can't find it.

Comment: You are welcome !  Equation $(4)$ in this answer can have an inifinite number of terms.

Comment: I see. And just one more thing. Could you explain how you got the inverted series?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no analytical solution, unless youintroduce a special function. With $\beta:=\dfrac\alpha2$, the geometry yields

$$\frac ca=\frac{\sin\beta}\beta=\text{sinc }\beta$$ and you can write

$$\beta=\text{sinc}^{-1}\frac ca.$$

For small angles, by Taylor you have approximately

$$\frac ca=1-\frac{\beta^2}6$$ or to the next order

$$\frac ca=1-\frac{\beta^2}6+\frac{(\beta^2)^2}{120}$$ which are linear and quadratic in $\beta^2$. (Below, the plots of these approximations, $x$ is $\beta^2$. The true curve is in blue.)

[image]

---

The worse error occurs for the half-turn, $2\beta=\pi$, and the approximated values for increasing degrees are

$$0.5887664832879,\\0.6395003848682,\\0.6365198876162,\\0.6366220276468,\\\cdots\\0.6366197723676.$$

Explicit formulas for the polynomial roots are available up to the fourth approximation.