# Make X the subject

Tags: calculus

The equation y(x)=sin(kx) where x needs to be the subject

Note:y function of x not y times x

What I did is x=1/ksin^-1(y(x))
However, x is still on the right-hand side.
How should I approach this further? Any suggestions?

Comment: If $y(x)$ means $y$ is a function of $x$ then you are done. However if $y(x)$ means multiplication then I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the equation to be solved is
$$x \times y=\sin(k x)$$ there is no analytical solutions and numerical methods are required.
We can make more or less accurate *approximations* .

To simplify the problem, let $kx=t$ and $a=\frac t k$ making the equation
$$\sin(t)=a t\qquad \text{with} \qquad 0 < a < 1$$

If I may suggest, have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation) of mine where the problem has been quite extensively discussed.